# Create Item task does not initiate 'On Creation' workflow in target list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

Background: Using SharePoint Online 2013 / SharePoint Designer 2013

I have two lists (A & B).

List A culminates by creating a new item in List B.

List B has a 'on item creation' workflow.

The WF associated with List B triggers fine when I create a new list item *manually*, but the workflow does not start when the list item is created by the List A workflow.

Having searched around it appears others have had this issue but there is little help in the way of reasons for it not working or even a workaround.

Can anyone shed any light on a solution to what seems to be a very simple need?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Quick question, are you a Farm Administrator?
I'm using SP 2010, and as farm admin, when i create a new item on a list with a workflow attached, it doesn't start, this is a patch from march I think, so try with another account.

Comment: Within the context of using Office365/SharePoint Online, yes I am a Farm Admin, although given I am using O365/SP Online, Microsoft handle all the server-side maintainance, so assuming I'm already fully patched, I'm looking for a client-side solution...

Comment: Have you tried with another account?

Answer (score 0):

I have opened an official support ticket with Microsoft as this has been recognised as an official bug in Office 365 SharePoint 2013